# ts Command Gives Me Wrong Datas on R

Tags: r, time-series

I work on a time series dataset. There are several columns. All the columns work truly when I want to transform data into time series with "ts" command except one.

```
examplets = ts(example, frequency = 4, start =c(2006,1))
```

I use this code for this data:

```
              V1
1 241,532,096.61
2 243,429,518.82
3 245,312,048.61
4 247,167,478.33
5 248,996,059.98
6 250,810,933.63
```

But when I want to view examplets the program gives me this:

```
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2006    1    2    3    4
2007    5    6    7    8
2008    9   10   11   12
2009   13   14   15   16
```

Why doesn't work ts command on this data? Please help me.

```
structure(list(V1 = c("241,532,096.61", "243,429,518.82", "245,312,048.61", 
"247,167,478.33", "248,996,059.98", "250,810,933.63", "252,616,842.95", 
"254,421,598.34", "256,246,935.93", "258,132,231.74", "260,114,608.34", 
"262,233,279.15", "264,538,402.85", "267,082,257.99", "269,886,727.28", 
"272,959,062.95", "276,308,630.00", "279,945,148.28", "283,849,923.78", 
"287,993,894.85", "292,356,218.98", "296,923,542.85", "301,661,097.26", 
"306,532,134.74", "311,518,557.89", "316,616,963.99", "321,801,431.39", 
"327,041,005.96", "332,318,347.29", "337,626,627.21", "342,937,997.04", 
"348,225,225.88", "353,480,627.00", "358,708,801.00", "363,896,106.64", 
"369,022,245.93", "374,081,370.68", "379,079,596.82", "383,999,104.05", 
"388,818,288.24", "393,531,274.65", "398,150,197.24", "402,661,471.98", 
"407,047,475.85", "411,292,940.00", "415,400,777.36", "419,348,734.32", 
"423,112,715.93", "426,690,500.69", "430,107,820.95", "433,372,967.62", 
"436,498,227.52", "439,515,985.68", "442,470,391.19", "445,373,742.84", 
"448,229,924.59", "451,058,449.52", "453,901,367.86", "456,772,481.48"
)), row.names = c(NA, -59L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you show the `example` data i..e `dput(example)`

Comment: I added it bottom of the message. Sorry I didn't know what is the dput command until you told me.

Comment: Your values have `,` in between and it is a string.  Is that separate values for each comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying the `ts` on the full `data.frame`, we can apply on the extracted column as a `vector`

```
ts(example$V1, frequency = 4, start =c(2006,1))
```

Comment: I want to give you vote but the site gives me "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." message. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.